# Performing a sensitivity analysis on a data frame using R

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to carry out a sensitivity analysis on a data frame in R. I'm very new to this, and so I could use some help please.

I have an output variable defined by a function of eight input variables; those are `'B','L','S','X1','X2','X3','X4','X5','X6','X7','X8'`. I need to figure out which of the eight variables is the 'key' variable.

`B` is normally distributed, the other variables have uniform distributions. `L` and `S` range from 0 to 1 in increments of 0.1 and the `X` variables range from 1 to 4 in increments of 1.

I set the quantile functions;

```
 q <- c("qnorm", "qunif", "qunif", "qunif", "qunif", "qunif", "qunif", "qunif", "qunif", "qunif", "qunif" )
 q.arg<- list(list(mean = 12473.68, sd = 2870.919) ,list(min=0,max=1),list(min=0,max=1),
                             list(min=1,max=4),list(min=1,max=4),list(min=1,max=4),list(min=1,max=4),
                            list(min=1,max=4),list(min=1,max=4),list(min=1,max=4),list(min=1,max=4))
```

Here's the function;

```
modelRun<-function(Input) {(Input[,1]) * (Input[,2]) * (Input[,3]) * 
   ((Input[,4] + Input[,5] + Input[,6] + Input[,7] + Input[,8]) + (Input[,9])
    + (Input[,10]) + (Input[,11])) / 32 }
```

Factors to be considered

```
factors<-c('B','L','S','X1','X2','X3','X4','X5','X6','X7','X8')
```

Now run the sensitivity analysis

```
library(sensitivity)
test <- fast99(modelRun, factors, n=1000, q=q, q.arg=q.arg)
 test
```

And the output

```
Call:
fast99(model = modelRun, factors = factors, n = 1000, q = q,     q.arg = q.arg)

Model runs: 11000 

Estimations of the indices:
   first order total order
B   0.06066269    0.111336
L          NaN         NaN
S          NaN         NaN
X1         NaN         NaN
X2         NaN         NaN
X3         NaN         NaN
X4         NaN         NaN
X5         NaN         NaN
X6         NaN         NaN
X7         NaN         NaN
X8         NaN         NaN
```

Here's where I'm confused. I've never done this before and I could use some help figuring out what I'm doing wrong.

What I'd actually like to do, is run the sensitivity analysis on my real data, but I'm completely lost at this point. Here's a sample;

```
B<-c(14524.12691,   9755.416062,    14022.21327,    7865.844439,    12770.56613,    14736.12471,    
     13287.55742,   15821.41177,    10444.19809,    14800.05292,    7542.670071,    16948.86227,    
     9454.267877,   12361.3193, 12770.56613)
L<-rep((0.5),15)
S<-rep((0.8),15)
X1<-c(3, 3, 3,  4,  3,  3,  4,  3,  3,  3,  4,  3,  3,  3,  3)
X2<-c(3, 4, 2,  4,  4,  2,  4,  3,  2,  4,  4,  3,  2,  3,  2)
X3<-c(4, 4, 4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  3,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4)
X4<-c(4, 4, 4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  3,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4)
X5<-c(4, 4, 4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4)
X6<-c(4, 4, 4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4)
X7<-c(3, 4, 3,  4,  3,  3,  4,  3,  3,  3,  4,  3,  3,  3,  3)
X8<-c(3, 3, 3,  4,  3,  3,  4,  3,  3,  3,  4,  3,  3,  3,  3)

data<-data.frame(B,L,S,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8)
```

Thank in advance for any help.